# How to migrate a bootable ubuntu installation from one partition to other

Tags: partitioning, migration

I have installed Ubuntu 14LTS on one of the two partitions of 32GB pen drive.

Now i want to have more space for Ubuntu partition. How can i migrate this bootable partition to partition.

Can i use `dd` to make a image of the partition and then migrate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use dd, and directly, if your current installation is on partition /dev/sda1 and you wanted to move it to /dev/sdb2 the command would be:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb2
```

Just be very careful when you issue the command, it's very powerful, and if you get the input file (if) and output file (of) wrong, you'll end up overwriting your useful partition with the blank one!

Alternatively you can make an image of the partition with:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of =/home/user/disk1.img
```

then restore it with

```
dd if=/home/user/disk1.img of=/dev/sdb2
```

The path and name of the image file are just examples, you can put it where you like, and call it what you like, so long as you use the .img file extension.

EDIT:

There's a useful link [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition), which will take you through generating a new UUID updating the MBR, grub, mtab and fstab, it should leave you with a working system. As it seems like you've already set up and cloned the partition, you probably only have to do some of the steps.

Comment: You do not need the .img file extension, you can use .raw or even no extension. You can also compress the raw image to take less space. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning#Examples_with_compression

Comment: Just had to set 'bootable' flag of the new partition using cfdisk.

Comment: But Ubuntu still shows only old size when executed 'df -h'. Its no utilizing the new space.

Comment: Command was 'dd if=~/backup.dat of=/dev/sdb2 bd=1M' I think block size is the culprit.